# Camel calling rest service cannot retrieve return object dto: JsonMappingException, No serializer for CachedOutputStream

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I have a maven multimodule project with two modules:

- a springboot running a rest service (on port 8081)
- a camel project who acts as proxy and calls the rest service (port 8080)

In camel project I have created a route builder like this:

```
restConfiguration().component("servlet")
  .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
  .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
  .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS")
  .contextPath("/").port(8080)
  .apiProperty("cors", "true");

  rest("/car").description("Cars rest service")
    .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
    .get("/{id}").description("Find car by id")
    .param().name("id").type(RestParamType.path)
    .description("The id of the car to get")
    .dataType("int").endParam()
    .to("http://localhost:8081?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

The rest service returns a `ResponseEntity<CarDto>` valid and not null (I have debugged it), but nevertheless camel project cannot get it, an exception is launched:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS).
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:275)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1110)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1135)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:69)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:32)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1419)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1147)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:977)
>   at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.marshal(JacksonDataFormat.java:154)

Then, instead of calling rest service I have added an controller-api with the same requestmapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/car/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<CarDto> findOne...
```

in camel project which returns a `CarDto` too. Camel calls it and works fine.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The REST endpoint defined in camel uses GET method which produces a message with empty body. This is different from the Spring controller in that the controller retrieves a CarDTO instance, which is missing from the camel route.

After the exposed rest endpoint receives the request, it should transform into another type, so your final endpoint consumes JSON, the following transformation step should be inserted

```
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, CarDTO.class)
```

A final point that I would like to add is that due to the fact that both consumer and producer handle the same headers, defined by the camel-http component, this seems to be very error prone if the consumed endpoint returns a header that causes an effect when submitted to the produced endpoint. This should be taken into account when a consumed HTTP message is forwarded to a produced HTTP message.